# VBA filter by multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel, range, autofilter

I'm trying to filter a list according to the values of multiple cells on another tab, but i just can't get it to work properly.

This is what i got:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$Y$129").AutoFilter Field:=13, 
 Criteria1:=Range("Formulas!A8:A10").Value
```

the problem is that it works with 1 cell, but not multiple as i have tried to do with the range A8:A10. The code as it is now only filters on the last defined cell- namely A10 - in stead of the whole range.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an Array variable, I've used `FiltArr`, and store all the values in your range that you want to filter by.

```
Dim FiltArr As Variant

' add all range values to array, use Transpose to get a 1-D array
FiltArr = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Formulas").Range("A8:A10").Value)

ActiveSheet.Range("A2:Y129").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=FiltArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```